# Preview fswebcam image as it takes picture

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi

I am currently using a USB webcam with a Raspberry Pi 3. At the moment as part of a lot of other code in Python it takes a picture using the camera and saves it to a specific directory. I was wondering whether there was any way of getting a preview of the image to show up on screen, similarly to how the picamera works:

`camera.start_preview()
 time.sleep(5)
 camera.capture('/home/pi/Downloads/image.jpg')
 camera.stop_preview()`

Is there an equivalent to this using fswebcam? The part of the code that takes the image is:

`from subprocess import call
 call(["fswebcam", "--no-banner", "image.jpg"])`

Ideally I would like it to preview the image on-screen for a set number of seconds before capturing it and saving it to the directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I made this kind of function for a commercial app. (no source code here, sorry)
Mixing fswebcam for capturing and other python code for previewing seems to be a bad idea, as the camera will hardly be available for them both.
(you may try to use "mplayer tv://" as the preview and launch fswebcam from another terminal to verify this point)

For the python approcah : as the most difficult part will be to display the preview, you should build your app around this feature. Saving a frame as an image will be easy from there.
I had some success working with Pygame, that can use v4l2 cameras, managing displays and user events.

In practice, look at https://gist.github.com/snim2/255151, the main pygame function you'll need are there.

Note : don't expect the refresh rate of the preview to be perfect. It will only be decent.
Not sure if it's the camera, v4l2, pygame or python that cause this ...

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. As links can change and become invalid over time, could you consider editing your answer to add the suggested function here? You can still include the link for context. Thanks!